# How can Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance) work in .Net Standard 2.0 application?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `.Net Standard2.0` library implemented both in `.Net Framework 4.6.1` and `.Net Core 3.1` which code as follow:

```cs
public class TcpServer
{
    public TcpServer()
    {
        // it will be error if delete the condition
        // and it nerver work in .net core 3.1 console application
#if NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
#endif
    }
}
```

How can i make `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)` work in `.Net Standard2.0` application?

**Update**

Modify file which is ended with `.csproj` and change `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` into `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>`.It will work!

Comment: That's something that should be called by the *application*, not the library

Comment: You don't, it is specific to .NETCore (aka .NET 5+).  If you use this library in a .NETCore app then be sure to make this call inside that app.

Comment: I firgured it out! Have a quick look! @HansPassant

Comment: Sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify file which is ended with .csproj and change netstandard2.0 into netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1